# scala.js's generated JavaScript cannot be called from HTML: "ReferenceError"

Tags: scala, scala.js

I set up a very simple scala.js project with this very simple "application":

```
package example

import org.scalajs.dom._

import scala.scalajs.js.JSApp

class EverythingWorks extends JSApp {

  def main() = {
    console.log("It works!")
  }
}
```

The corresponding HTML looks the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    example.EverythingWorks().main();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I did `sbt fastOptJS`, copied the generated JS file to `js/app.js` and the `js.map` file next to `app.js`.

Instead of printing "It works!" on the console, I get `ReferenceError: example is not defined`. I double-checked that `app.js` is found from the HTML.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main class should be `object`, not `class`.

Answer (score 0):

The ScalaJS build process does "dead code elimination." This reduces the size of the build dramatically. However, unless you tell it that some of your top level stuff is NOT dead code, it will be eliminated.

That means you have to use the `@JSExport` annotation to tell ScalaJS not to remove your top level methods and objects.

From [this introduction](http://lihaoyi.github.io/hands-on-scala-js/), the example code:

```
@JSExport
object ScalaJSExample {
  @JSExport
  def main(canvas: html.Canvas): Unit = {
```

Comment: This solved it for me, I could not get it to work with JSApp.